# Android ROOM- How can I run a query on each cell inside my custom calendar?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-calendar

I have a [customCalendarView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcDrt.png).

To create this I used an ArrayAdapter class (MyGridAdapter).

When a user clicks on a square in the calendar, they are taken to an activity in which they can save a logEntry containing some information along with the date on which was clicked on the calendar.

This log entry is saved to a database.

I would like to display a small circle on each square in the calendar when a log entry is present on that specific day.

I have created a query inside my logEntriesDao which returns all logs with the same date as the date which is passed to it.

`@Query("SELECT * FROM log_entries_table WHERE log_entries_table.date = :date " )
    LiveData<List<Log_Entries>> getAllFromWorkoutLogEntriesonDate(String date);`

How could I run this query on each cell in my calendar and then set my circle imageView visibility to VISIBLE on each calendar cell in which a log is present?

**CustomCalendarView**

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout {
    ImageButton NextButton, PreviousButton;
    TextView CurrentDate;
    GridView gridView;
    public static final int MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS = 42;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Context context;
    MyGridAdapter myGridAdapter;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
   // SimpleDateFormat eventDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(("yyyy-MM-dd"),Locale.ENGLISH);

    SimpleDateFormat eventDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(("dd-MM-yyyy"),Locale.ENGLISH);

    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Log_Entries> eventsList = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(final Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        InitializeLayout();
        SetUpCalendar();

        PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                SetUpCalendar();
            }
        });

        NextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                SetUpCalendar();

            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);

                final String date = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));

                Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), WorkoutButtonsActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(WorkoutButtonsActivity.EXTRA_DATE, date);
                getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr ) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void InitializeLayout(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, this);
        NextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        PreviousButton = view.findViewById(R.id.previousBtn);
        CurrentDate = view.findViewById(R.id.current_Date);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    }

    private void SetUpCalendar(){

        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        CurrentDate.setText(currentDate);
        dates.clear();
        Calendar monthCalendar= (Calendar) calendar.clone();
        monthCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        int FirstDayofMonth = monthCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) -1;
        monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, - FirstDayofMonth);

        while (dates.size() < MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS){
            dates.add(monthCalendar.getTime());
            monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        myGridAdapter = new MyGridAdapter(context,dates,calendar,eventsList);
        gridView.setAdapter(myGridAdapter);

    }
    }
```

**MyGridAdapter**

```
public class MyGridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List<Date> dates;
    Calendar currentDate;

    List<Log_Entries> logs;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyGridAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Date> dates, Calendar currentDate, List<Log_Entries> logs){
        super(context, R.layout.single_cell_layout);

        this.dates = dates;
        this.currentDate = currentDate;
        this.logs = logs;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Date monthDate = dates.get(position);
        Calendar dateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateCalendar.setTime(monthDate);
        int DayNo = dateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int displayMonth = dateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
        int displayYear = dateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentMonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int currentYear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int currentDay = currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_cell_layout, parent,false);
        }

        if (displayMonth == currentMonth && displayYear == currentYear){
            view.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        }
        else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#cccccc"));
        }

        TextView Day_Number = view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day);
        Day_Number.setText(String.valueOf(DayNo));

        Calendar eventCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if(DayNo == currentDay && displayMonth == eventCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 && displayYear == eventCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
            Day_Number.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF33"));
        }
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < logs.size(); i++){
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dates.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(@Nullable Object item) {
        return dates.indexOf(item);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dates.get(position);
    }
}
```

**LogEntries Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "log_entries_table")
public class Log_Entries {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int log_id;

    @ForeignKey(entity = Junction.class, parentColumns = "exercise_workout_id", childColumns = "junction_id")
    private int junction_id;

    @ForeignKey(entity = Junction.class, parentColumns = "workout_id", childColumns = "workout_id")
    private int workout_id;


   double total_weight_lifted;

   int set_number;

   int reps;

    public  String date;

    public Log_Entries(int junction_id, int workout_id, double total_weight_lifted, int set_number, int reps, String date) {
        this.junction_id = junction_id;
        this.workout_id = workout_id;
        this.total_weight_lifted = total_weight_lifted;
        this.set_number = set_number;
        this.reps = reps;
        this.date = date;
    }


    public void setLog_id(int log_id) {
        this.log_id = log_id;
    }

    public int getLog_id() {
        return log_id;
    }


    public int getJunction_id() {
        return junction_id;
    }


    public double getTotal_weight_lifted() {
        return total_weight_lifted;
    }

    public void setTotal_weight_lifted(double total_weight_lifted) {
        this.total_weight_lifted = total_weight_lifted;
    }

    public int getSet_number() {
        return set_number;
    }


    public int getReps() {
        return reps;
    }

    public int getWorkout_id() {
        return workout_id;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about next general schema:

1. Your query request should be one-time shot on all dates visible on your Calendar. Otherwise it's not optimal. I think you can get either date range (for example, 01.05.20..31.05.20) or date's list (01.05,02.05,...,31.05) and set this range (list) as a parameter to your query (list of dates or date1|date2 for range).
2. You should change your query to get list of dates, where log is present. Let's say you have 6 dates with logs, so your query should return list with 6 dates.
3. If you're using MVVM pattern, you can observe your LiveData-result from ROOM at your Activity (observing it you'll get list of 6 dates on activity create and 7 dates after you add some log with your second activity).
4. You can set then your date's list to your adapter and implement there your UI-changes (circles, background whatever).

Comment: The problem I am having is that I have a `calendarFragment` which then calls the `customCalendarView` class to set up the calendar. I am unsure of where to call the query (passing a list of all dates to my `logEntriesViewModel`). Can I call this query directly from the 'customCalendarView`?

Comment: As I see on image you've attached you have some calendar. And user can choose month. So the right moment to start observe your data with logs at current month - is the moment when you set your current month (I suppose it's you SetupCalendarMethod). Then you observe your LiveData and with getting LiveData value you put the list with data to your adapter where you could play with UI as you want. But if you are not familiar with LiveData you should read about it and to be ready to try-and-mistake a lot )

Comment: Thankyou, I have read the `LiveData` documentation and have watched the view Youtube videos on it. I have read that it is bad practice to observe `LiveData` outside of a fragment/ activity and my `CustomCalendarView` class extends LinearLayout, therefore I am unsure what to do. I have posted a more detailed question explaining the problem in more detail. Thankyou very much for the guidance.

Comment: Honestly, I have no experience in observing LiveData inside CustomView. I suppose there are two ways for experiments: 1. Use your host Fragment as a lifecycleowner of your LiveData (inside your View you can get reference to fragment) 2. To observe LiveData inside CustomView either with observeForever() method or to implement interface LifecycleOwner by your View. But as I said it's a way for experiments and "try-mistake-try-again" attempts